# Best way to make images changeable in a Visual Studio (WPF) project

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

I want to make a visual studio project customizable. In a way that several builds uses several images.

For e. g. build one has image1.jpg in its info-dialog. Build two has image2.jpg in its info-dialog.

Therefore I created sevaral build-configurations. But how can I handle different images for different builds in a best way?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple resource dictionaries and load the right one in your App class based on the current build configuration using preprocessor directives:

```
    var myResourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();

#if DEBUG
    myResourceDictionary.Source =
        new Uri("/DllName;component/Resources/DebugResources.xaml",
                UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
#endif
#if RELEASE
    myResourceDictionary.Source =
        new Uri("/DllName;component/Resources/ReleaseResources.xaml",
                UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
#endif

    this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(myResourceDictionary);
```

Answer (score 0):

we have different builds on our build server and change the images there and not in code.

Comment: I do not intend to do that in code. But how do you change the images?

Comment: pre build scripts that simply replace images before build start, the images that should be replaced have same names of course

Comment: OK! But if I change the build-configuration definied prebuild-commands will not change. How do you change the prebuild-command depending on the build-configuration?

Comment: app1 has build1, app2 has build2 - we define prebuildscripts where we copy the images

Comment: I see! You changed the files by using like this:

if MyRelease == $(ConfigurationName) (copy /y "C:\file.bmp" "C:\bin\Release\file.bmp"

Thanks :)